# Assign input to a div?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a multi step form by getting questions and answer alternatives from a mysql database through php/ajax (No page reload is necessary). I do however seem to have problems submitting the data if a .php page generates all the divs(at least that is a theory as to why it won't work). The way I am trying to do it seems to work fine if I write it all directly in HTML, but that would not be dynamic and therefore useless for this particular task. Is it possible to create a form like psuedo-coded underneath?

```
<div>
 <div id="stepone" class="section"> </div>
 <div id="steptwo" class="section"> </div>
 <div id="stepthree" class="section"> </div>
 <div id="stepfour" class="section"> </div>
</div>
```

And then have a PHP site generate the **input** tags and assign it to the correct div, so that the divs are created in HTML/JS but the inputs like checkboxes and textareas are generated dynamically through PHP. I can't seem to think of a good way to do this?

Worth mentioning that this page is made in JQM (jQuery Mobile) so I think the different div-roles can appear problematic for this task.

A generated question in my PHP script will be something like this:

```
<form id="eval_form">
 <h3>Hva tenkte du om møtet?</h3>
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true" id="2">   
   <input type="checkbox" name="res[2][1]" id="2_1" value="1"><label for="2_1">asd1</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="res[2][2]" id="2_2" value="2"><label for="2_2">asd2</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="res[2][3]" id="2_3" value="3"><label for="2_3">asd3</label>
  </fieldset>
 <h3>Hva følte du om møtet?</h3>
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true" id="3"> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="res[3][1]" id="3_1" value="1"><label for="3_1">test1</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="res[3][2]" id="3_2" value="2"><label for="3_2">test2</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="res[3][3]" id="3_3" value="3"><label for="3_3">test3</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="res[3][4]" id="3_4" value="4"><label for="3_4">test4</label>
  </fieldset>
 <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn">
</form>
```

The code for my demo program looks like this, and it has no problems being posted:

```
<form id="eval_form">

        <!-- STEP 1-->
        <div data-role="content" id="form1" class="section">
            <input type="text" name="answer[1]" placeholder="Write something..." class="required"></input><p/>
            <input type="text" name="answer[2]" placeholder="Write something..." class="required"></input><p/>
            <input type="button" name="next1" value="Next" id="next1" onClick="toggleVisibility('form2')" class="next-btn"/>
        </div>

        <!-- STEP 2-->
        <div data-role="content" id="form2" class="section">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                <input type="radio" name="answer[4]" id="1" value="1" class="required"/><label for="1">Value 1</label>
                <input type="radio" name="answer[4]" id="2" value="2" class="required"/><label for="2">Value 2</label>
                <input type="radio" name="answer[4]" id="3" value="3" class="required"/><label for="3">Value 3</label>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="button" id="back2" value="Back" onClick="toggleVisibility('form1')" class="back-btn">
            <input type="button" name="next2" value="Next" id="next2" onClick="toggleVisibility('form3')" class="next-btn"/>
        </div>

        <!-- STEP 3-->
        <div data-role="content" id="form3" class="section">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true" class="required">
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer[5][1]" id="1" value="1"/><label for="1">Testie</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer[5][2]" id="2" value="2"/><label for="2">Testoe</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer[5][3]" id="3" value="3"/><label for="3">Tester</label>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="answer[3]" placeholder="Write something..." class="required"></input><p/>
            <input type="button" id="back3" value="Back" class="back-btn" onClick="toggleVisibility('form2')">
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn"/>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Ajax function to send the data:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
            $("#submit").click(function() 
            {
                var data_string = $('#eval_form').serialize();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'add.php',
                    data:data_string,
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        $("#eval").html(response);
                    }
                });         
            })
    });
```

Comment: COuld you give an example of what you would expect? I'm not quite sure what you mean by generate input tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way id do it is just have a single div to contain your steps

```
<div id="stepContainer" >
    <input type="text" id="step1Input" />
</div>
```

Something like that.

The ajax query will take any elements within the step container and submit them appropriatley via GET/POST to your php/asp whatever page does your server logic.  When it returns it can return some confirmation or the html required for the next step.

Once you have this returned html or built the new html in javascript based on the response from the server you can replace the contents of the `stepContainer` with the new html.  This will then act as step 2.

You may want to have a hidden div or some counter in javascript to keep track of which is your current step.

It may even be wise to use json return from the server which can allow you to pass more information across (well more easily anyway), allowing you to have error messages, confirmations, html etc embedded in the single response.

Comment: I must have written my question a bit unclear. I was really asking how to generate the poll without having PHP write the actual div containers. At the moment I just launch a single PHP file that writes all the code after checking for the questions in MySQL. It works nicely when I see each page and click next to show the next step and so forth, but when I try to post it - nothing happens. However the same code works like a charm if I don't generate the poll with PHP, but just write it raw in the HTML file.

Comment: I even tried to get my PHP script to only generate a single page of questions to submit, but still no success. It just behaves as a button without any function.

Comment: Problem is that whenever I generate the poll with PHP the submit function doesnt seem to work, however it works perfectly when the poll is made directly in the HTML file. But I will try to make a JavaScript that can arrange the poll for me, it's just more work as I have to pass all question ids, types, descriptions, alternative ids and alternative descriptions through Json or something before I can generate the poll with JS.

Comment: You must be outputting something wrong in PHP as there should be not reason for it not to work.  PHP just generates your html for you so once its at the frontend there is absolutley no difference whether it came from PHP or you wrote it in HTML.

Comment: Hmm cheers. I will have to look closer into the PHP code then. I just assumed the error was there somewhere as I've made 3 different versions now from scratch and they all seem to fail at the same place.

Comment: I have posted the exact thing the PHP prints out now, as well as the working HTML only version. Can't spot the difference. But there was an error with the name and id. Even when I put my PHP script that is recieving the form to only echo "test"; nothing happens.

Comment: Surely you're expecting the demo html and our generated one from php to be the same?

Comment: well one uses the name `res` and the other uses the name `answer` surely this is a problem?

Comment: It's not a problem until I recieve the data back, my recieving PHP script atm are only supposed to echo "test". But it doesnt happen.

Comment: You should start off simple, start by sending an empty form and printing a result in php regardless of the inputs.  If this works then start expanding the functionality.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I've downsized it drastically already - but perhaps going back to nothing would help me. How did I not think about that? Muchos gracias:)

Comment: It does most likely have something to do with PHP generating the poll. I can get the submit button to work as long as I don't generate it with PHP. My empty form with only 1 hidden value and a submit button works if I post it in HTML but not if I generate it by PHP. Sooo annoying!